# PHP and PDO: online and offline user status

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on my site and I would like to add a user status to see who is online and who is offline on my site. I really don't know how I can do that. I have already created the Member Area and I just need this to see the activity.

Just an idea of my code (not full):

MySQL:
[image: MySQL table screenshot]

Sign Up Page and if no errors:

```
if(empty($errors))
{
    $request = $pdo -> prepare("INSERT INTO users SET username = ?, e_mail = ?, password = ?, join_date = NOW()");
    $password = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $request -> execute([$_POST["username"], $_POST["e-mail"], $password]);
    $_SESSION["flash-message"]["success"] = ["Compte créé", "Votre compte a été créé avec succès. Vous pouvez dès à présent vous connecter avec."];
    header("Location: sign-in.php");
    exit();
}
```

Sign In Page:

```
if(empty($errors))
{
    $request = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username OR e_mail = :username");
    $request -> execute(["username" => $_POST["username"]]);
    $user = $request -> fetch();
    if($user && password_verify($_POST["password"], $user -> password))
    {
        $_SESSION["signed-in"] = $user;
        $_SESSION["flash-message"]["success"] = ["Connexion réussie", "Vous êtes maintenant connecté(e)."];
        header("Location: account.php");
        exit();
    }
    elseif($user && !empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["password"]))
    {
        $errors["password"] = "Votre mot de passe est incorrect.";
    }
}
```

Sign Out Page:

```
<?php

session_start();

unset($_SESSION["signed-in"]);
$_SESSION["flash-message"]["success"] = ["Déconnexion réussie", "Vous êtes maintenant déconnecté(e)."];
header("Location: .");
exit();

?>
```

My users are stored in a session called: ["signed-in"]. Now I need a solution to do that. What I need to do exactly? Thank you.

Comment: _“What I need to do exactly?”_ – learn how to do some basic research …? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+mysql+show+online+users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a last_access column to your user table, and every time someone who is logged in visits a page, run this query:

```
"UPDATE users SET last_access='NOW()' WHERE id='$user->id'"
```

Then it would be easy to assign online/offline status depending on when a user last visited a page:

```
"SELECT username, 
(CASE 
WHEN last_access > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE THEN 'online' 
ELSE 'offline' 
END) AS user_status 
FROM users"
```

Comment: That status would never get reset, if the user just closes their window/tab without actually logging out. The usual approach for this is to store the _timestamp_ of them last accessing any page, and then consider all users for which that last access timestamp is not older than X as “online”, and the rest as “offline”.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have a users list and I would like to display the user status for each user. What I need to do for that? I want to add Online for online users and Offline for offline users. Currently I have this: http://prntscr.com/a4wcy2

Comment: Everyone that is selected by `"SELECT username FROM users WHERE last_access > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE"` is online, and everyone that is selected by `"SELECT username FROM users WHERE last_access < NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE"` is offline.

Notice the < and >, which is the only difference in the selections.

Comment: Okay, but by default NOW() is the current time and I would like to display that as a word. If user is online, display just Online and if not, display Offline.

Comment: Can you just use PHP to assign the strings "online" and "offline" to a $status variable?  You can run your first query to get everyone who is online, and display those first, then run a second query to get everyone who is offline, and display those second.

Comment: To display online and offline user, I need to do a req like this? `SELECT username FROM users WHERE last_activity > NOW() AND last_activity < NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE`

Comment: You can use an if statement to directly assign a status in your SQL code:

`SELECT username,
(
 WHEN last_access > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE THEN 'online'
 ELSE 'offline'
) AS user_status
FROM users`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103863/discussion-between-dave-and-uptop-14).

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you have no way to know if a user is still active.
The only thing you can do is to create a column `last_action` (datetime) in your user table and update the datetime everytime the user do an action.

Consequently, you can suppose a user is still active if his last action was X min ago.

Comment: Okay, but What I need to put in the req to update the date?